# Google Drive upload limit using a third party aplicattion

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to know about the Google Drive upload limit, per day, using a third party aplicattion, like SyncbackPro.

Regards,

Adriano

Answer (score 1):

There is a 750 GB upload per day limit.

There is a 10TB download per day limit

> For each account or Team Drive, the maximum individual file size that you can upload or sync is 5 TB. After you've uploaded 750 GB in 1 day, you'll be blocked from uploading additional files that day

See:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en